# WPF datagridtemplatecolumn editrowending event not raised

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am having a problem whereby the `DataGrid EditRowEnding` event is not firing.

I have a `DataGrid` which has a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and if the value of this column is changed and the row loses focus the `EditRowEnding` event is not fired. I assume this is because the `DataGrid` has no knowledge of the child in the `DataGridTemplateColumn` changing.

Is there anyway I can inform the `DataGrid` that the custom cell has changed.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="Users" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" Margin="0,10,0,0" 
              Style="{StaticResource AlternatingDataGridStyle}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event RowEditEnding] = [Action ModifyUser($eventArgs)]" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <PasswordBox customBehaviours:PasswordHelper.Attach="True"
                                     customBehaviours:PasswordHelper.Password="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Role">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Role, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserRoleEnumProvider}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks.